# What is the Outlook equivalent of Thunderbird's IMAP "Order Received" column?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, imap

I need uniquely identify e-mails on the same IMAP server, across Outlook and Thunderbird configurations. Thunderbird's "Order Received" is a great tool for this, because the result is a simple integer number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No equivalent in Outlook. But the best way to uniquely identify emails is the **Message-Id** header because it is stored right in the email itself.

Comment: :/ Unfortunate. `Message-Id` header is not particularly human-transferrable.